# Javascript: Unable to access internal functions from functions passed from outside

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project, in which, I want to write some plugin type of code to let the developer extend the functionality of its functions. Lets suppose, I want to build a calculator, with the support of adding functionality to it on the fly:

```
function newCalc(newFn) {
  var fns = $.extend({
    add: function(a,b) {
        done(a+b);
    }
  }, newFn);

  var done = function(num) {
    alert('Outcome is: ' + num);
  }

  return fns;
}

var calc = newCalc({
  substract: function(a,b) {
    done(a-b);
  }
});

calc.add(4, 2);
calc.substract(4, 2);
```

However, I am not getting the results as I expected. `calc.add()` works just fine, but `calc.substract()` complains about unavailability of `done()` function.

Can anybody please help me out with this problem? How can I make done accessible to substract as well?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/PrakharMishra/p4egvuf7/1/

Comment: This is because `done` is an internal function and is not returned

Comment: I am not executing `substract()` from outside, I am just passing it to a function (newCalc), where `done()` is available. I am executing it just like `add()` method.

Comment: Also just an advice, if you are making a library or a reusable component, try not using jQuery. It will add dependency to user who is extending it. Try as far as possible to use vanilla JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `done` is a inner function and not exposed outside.
When you do `return fns;`, `new Calc` will only have `fns` and no other value.

You can use `this` keyword to assign function/variables to current context. Remember, just assigning `this.prop` but do not return it. If you return it, it will become a public property. Not returning will keep it private, but it will be accessible across all instances.

You can try something like this:

#### Code

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/p4egvuf7/4/).

```js
function newCalc(newFn) {
  var add = function(a, b) {
    done(a + b);
  }

  // This is a private function. 
  // Accessible across all objects but is not available outside
  this.done = function(num) {
    alert('Outcome is: ' + num);
  }

  // Add default properties
  var retObj = {
    add: add
  };

  // Add dynamic properties that are passed as parameters
  var keys = Object.keys(newFn);

  // Loop over all properties passed in object
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    retObj[keys[i]] = newFn[keys[i]];
  }
  return retObj;
}

var calc = newCalc({
  substract: function(a, b) {
    done(a - b);
  }
});

calc.add(4, 2);
calc.substract(4, 2);

console.log(calc)
calc.done(1 + 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `done` in the `newCalc` function is only accessible inside the function. And when you return the variable `fns`, the variable `done` is not accessible on the outside.

Here is the workaround:

```
function newCalc(newFn) {
    var fns = $.extend({
        add: function(a,b) {
            this.done(a+b);
        },
        done: function(num){
            alert('Outcome is: ' + num);
        }
    }, newFn);
    return fns;
}

var calc = newCalc({
    substract: function(a,b) {
        this.done(a-b);
    }
});
```

When you return `fns`, the done is also included in it.

And for initializing another variable `calc`. It should be like this:

```
var calc = newCalc({
    substract: function(a,b) {
        this.done(a-b);
    }
});
```

Notice that I put `this` on `this.done(a-b)`. The `this` object is referencing to the `fns` that `newCalc` returned.

So there will be no ReferenceError statements occur. When you run `calc.add(4, 2);` and `calc.subtract(4, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without big change like shown below.

```
function newCalc(newFn) {
    var fns = $.extend({
    add: function(a,b) {
        done(a+b);
    }
  }, newFn);

  this.done = function(num) {
    alert('Outcome is: ' + num);
  }

  return fns;
}

var calc = newCalc({
    substract: function(a,b) {
    done(a-b);
  }
});

calc.add(4, 2);
calc.substract(4, 2);
```